# TortoiseSVN cherrypicking

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, cherry-pick

I'm about to merge certain revisions from trunk into a release-branch.
I've checked with mergeinfo how many revisions are eligible to get merged, and that were 42.
Although it's definitely possible and not too hard to check each revision log and decide whether it should be merged or not. I would then check the logs with TortoiseSVN and use the command line `svn merge -c rev1,rev2` function or `-r` for ranges of course.

I was wondering if TortoiseSVN has a tool to make this cherrypicking a lot easier. I've googled for it, but found out that only probably TortoiseGit has it.

Any other methods which makes this process easier (and faster) are also welcome!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I know nothing about TortoiseGit but TortoiseSVN has quite a decent "Merge" dialogue. In the "Revision range to merge" section, select "Show log" and chose as many revisions as you want:

[image: TortoiseSVN Merge]

Additionally, revisions that are already merged will be grayed-out:

[image: Grayed-out revisions]

Comment: This is just awesome. This is exactly what I hoped to see actually. I'm not that into merging with TortoiseSVN and always did it from commandline. I never saw the merging option, but that was because I always was looking in my repo browser. Never knew it you should do it from working copy. I've still got much to learn about SVN. Thanks!